# Summing the content of two HTML template bindings with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two bindings created by filters that are displayed as below on my website:

```
{{BINDING1}} + {BINDING2}}
```

Both bindings are numbers so right now the output would look like for example:

4+3

However I would like for it to appear as

7

in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should show `4+3=7`: `{{BINDING1}} + {{BINDING2}}={{BINDING1 + BINDING2}}`